# how do i ensure correct routes when coding image upload in rails?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I tried to code image upload with rails 4 and I've already installed Paperclip.

The error message is:

> "No route matches {:action=>"photoupload", :controller=>"users",
>   :id=>"4"} missing required keys: [:user_id]"

This is my `route.rb` file:

```
resources :users, path: '' do
 patch '/photoupload', to: 'users#photoupload'
end
```

This is my controller code:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
 private
  def photoupload
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
        if @user.update(params.require(:user).permit(:user_id))
            format.js { render json: {photo: true} }
        else
            format.js { render json: @user.errors }
        end
    end
  end
end
```

This is my model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :avatar, styles: { :medium => "200x200>", :thumb => "100x100>" }
  validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, :content_type => /^image\/(png|gif|jpeg|jpg)/
end
```

This is my users show view:

```
<%= form_tag user_photoupload_path, method: :patch, id: 'photoinfo', remote: true, html: { multipart: true } do %>
 <div class="photoPreview">
  <%= icon('upload', '', class: 'photoUpload') %>
  <p id="uploadClick">Click to Upload</p>
 </div>

 <%= file_field_tag :avatar, accept: 'image/png,image/gif,image/jpeg, image/jpg', id: 'uploadAvatar' %>
 <p class="deletePhoto">Delete</p>
 <%= submit_tag 'Submit Photo', id: 'submitPhoto' %>

<% end %>
```

This is my javascript file:

```
function circleImageClick () {
 $('.deletePhoto').hide();
 $('.photoPreview').click(function() {
  $(this).attr('disabled', 'true');
  $('#uploadAvatar').trigger('click');
 });
 $("#uploadAvatar").change(function(){
  $('.photoPreview').removeAttr('disabled');
  readURL(this);
 });
}

function readURL(input) {
 if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
  var reader = new FileReader();

  reader.onload = function (e) {
   $('.photoPreview').css('background', 'url(' + e.target.result + ')');
   $('.photoUpload, #uploadClick').hide();
  }
  $('.deletePhoto').show();

  reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
 }
}

function deletePhoto () {
 $('.deletePhoto').click(function() {
  $('.deletePhoto').hide();
  $('#uploadAvatar').val('');
  $('.photoPreview').css('background', '');
  $('.photoUpload, #uploadClick').show();
 });
}

user_photoupload PATCH /:user_id/photoupload(.:format)               
users#photoupload
GET  / users#index
POST / users#create
```

The errors which are in lines 77,78 and 83 are in the photoupload action.

This is the method definition:

```
   class UsersController < ApplicationController                                                                   
     private                                                                                                            
     def photoupload
        @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
        respond_to do |format|
            if @user.update(params.require(:user).permit!
77              format.js { render json: {photo: true} }
78          else
                format.js { render json: @user.errors }
            end
        end
     end                                                                                                            
83 end
```

Comment: I made a separate model for the photos and this works flawlessly. In your case, you have no separate model for the pictures, but a User model with the necessary columns for the pictures such as image_content_type, image_file_size etc.. right ? I am no expert in routing but it seems your form_tag makes a reference to photos as a submodel: user_photoupload_path (yet I am not sure. Maybe someone will direct you..)

Comment: is it possible to show all your routes? (you can type a dummy address such as http://localhost:3000/users/1/whatever and they should show up)

Comment: is it routes on cmd or routes.rb?

Comment: just run your server and copy the above linkin the address bar of your browser. This will create a routing error and you will see all available routes (according to what has been set up in your routes.rb file). But Mukesh answer may just work fine, you can try it first.

Comment: @Maxence i have included the routes

Comment: Mukesh suggestion didnt work

Answer (score 0):

Update it

```
params.require(:user).permit(:user_id)
```

with

```
params.require(:user).permit(:id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your `routes` from:

```
resources :users, path: '' do
  patch '/photoupload', to: 'users#photoupload'
end
```

to:

```
resources :users, path: '' do
  patch '/photoupload', to: 'users#photoupload', on: :member
end
```

And update

```
params.require(:user).permit(:user_id)
```

to:

```
params.require(:user).permit!
```

Comment: did that but to no avail

Comment: Are you getting the same error? Please include the full stacktrace.

Comment: C:/loccaff/app/controllers/users_controller.rb:77: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting ')' format.js { render json: {photo: true} } ^ C:/loccaff/app/controllers/users_controller.rb:78: syntax error, unexpected keyword_else, expecting keyword_end else ^ C:/loccaff/app/controllers/users_controller.rb:83: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting end-of-input end ^

Comment: Looks like you have syntax error in `users_controller.rb:77`, update your question with the contents of the `users_controller.rb` for review.

Comment: You are missing `)` in `@user.update(params.require(:user).permit!`. Change it to `@user.update(params.require(:user).permit!)`

Comment: thanks for that but now the error is undefined local variable or method `user_photoupload_path' in users show

Comment: it is on the first line